# Generating set of Baire sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I got the following statement to prove:

Let $X$ locally compact and $\operatorname{Ba}(X)$ the Baire-$\sigma$-algebra, i. e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which all functions in $f \in C_c(X, \mathbb C)$ are measurable. Then $\operatorname{Ba}(X)$ is generated by $\mathcal E = \{[f > 0] = \{x \in X \mid f(x) > 0\} \mid 0 \leq f \in C_c(X, \mathbb C)\}$.

What I could show is the following:
"$\sigma(\mathcal E) \subseteq \operatorname{Ba}(X)$"

Since $H=\{z \in \mathbb C: \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0\}$ is open in $\mathbb C$ we have for a $f \in C_c(X, \mathbb C)$ that $[f > 0] = f^{-1}(H) \in \operatorname{Ba}(X)$. Hence it follows that $\sigma(\mathcal E) \subseteq \operatorname{Ba}(X)$.

But I really struggle to show that $\operatorname{Ba}(X) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal E)$. I know that it is sufficient to show that a $f \in C_c(X, \mathbb C)$ is measurable in $\sigma(\mathcal E)$, but I couldn't find a way to prove that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $f\in C_c(X)$. Standard construction: For $n=1,2\dots$ and $j\in\Bbb Z$ define $$E_{n,j}=\{x:j/n<f(x)\le(j+1)/n\}$$and set $$\phi_n=\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}\frac jn\chi_{E_{n,j}}.$$Then $\phi_n$ is $\sigma(\mathcal E)$-measurable and $\phi_n\to f$ (uniformly).